# How Can I run Selenium Test Automation on IE 11 without an Active logged on user session

Tags: python, selenium

I have an application that **runs on IE only** and I am in the process of automating some stuff on it. The challenge am having is that, The application doesn't launch when I don't have an Active logged on session on the server from where am testing from (am connecting via RDP). Its very inconveniencing that you cannot run tests via IE in the "dead of the night" without a logged on user session. I have done lots of research and I don't seem to get a conclusive answer whether there is any workaround for this.
To Simulate this:
My environment python 3.9 , IE11 , Windows server 2019

1. script to launch Google

   from selenium import webdriver
   from time import sleep
   url='https://www.google.com/'
   driver = webdriver.Ie(r'C:\IEDriverServer\IEDriverServer.exe')
   driver.get(url)
   sleep(1)
   driver.quit()
2. create a Batch file to launch the python script
   "C:\TEST\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\TEST\test.py"
   EXIT
3. schedule the batch script to run using windows scheduler
4. Close the logged on session. in my case the scripts are running from windows server 2019.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKaM9.png)

Note that, there is no issue when using chrome hence suspect its a limitation on the IE itself.

Comment: You are sleeping for one second and quitting the browser then. Experiment doing something on the script to see if there are results, or just remove the `driver.quit()` and log in manually to see if there is a browser IE session left open after you run the script in scheduler.

Comment: sounds like a scheduled task problem...  I would start researching with this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865653/how-to-troubleshoot-windows-scheduled-task-not-running

Comment: @Niloct well, I think you didn't understand the issue. If you check carefully, you will note that the problem is with IE launching the page. click on the results and see. As Indicated, Same script is loading the page using Chrome/Chrome driver.

Comment: @pcalkins Scheduler is not the issue here. check the "results" The scheduler is triggering the script as expected. problem is that IE doesnt launch the page. As indicated I have tested the very same script with chrome and the page is launched successfully.

Comment: looks like what you'd get if the security zones aren't all set the same.